# ActiveMQ SocketException

Tags: spring, tomcat6, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm running into a problem every two months or so. My activemq server dies and the log is full with SocketExceptions.

I have a PHP application using stomp to send messages to ActiveMQ and
a Java application to consume the messages.

I have activemq on another server where only java applications are used when sending/consuming messages and it has never failed like this. I think there is somthing 
wrong with Stomp.

The stomp code is very basic and does not send anything odd. Only messages with message properties set. The stomp code closes the connection after every message sent.

I've looked at lsof and there is nothing out of order there.

netstat does however have alot of:

> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:61616         127.0.0.1:46280         CLOSE_WAIT

And the ActiveMQ Log shows alot of this

> 2011-04-28 12:43:09,819 | ERROR |
>   Could not accept connection :
>   java.net.SocketException: Too many
>   open files |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector
>   | ActiveMQ Transport Server:
>   tcp://0.0.0.0:61616

I'm using:

> ActiveMQ 5.4.2,
>   Tomcat 6.0.20,
>   Debian 5.0.3,
>   PHP 5.2.6,
>   Stomp revision 43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are opening a lot connections in your java program, and then you are hitting your ulimit -n. Close Connections after usage or use a connection pool.

As a wourkaround you can raise your open file limit via sysctl, see a [tutorial here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm).

Comment: The java application is going to be replaced soon so I will go with your ulimit solution for now.

Comment: you replacing java with what programming language?

is it because of the queuing that in the end you want replace the java?